# Serialize model fields into nested object/dict

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

Imagine the following model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    address_streetname = models.CharField()
    address_housenumber = models.CharField()
    address_zip = models.CharField()
```

I have a django rest framework `ModelSerializer` that exposes all the fields.
But I would like to be able to serialize the address fields into a dict. So when serialized to json output would be:

```
{
    name: 'Some name',
    address: {
        streetname: 'This is a test',
        housenumber: '23',
        zip: '1337',
    }
}
```

I tried creating creating a `AddressSerializer`

```
class Address(object):
    ...

class AddressSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    streetname = serializers.CharField()
    housenumber = serializers.CharField()
    zip = serializers.CharField()
    ...
```

and then set the `PersonSerializer.address` to use the `AddressSerializer`

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    address = AddressSerializer()
```

This results in my schema being correct. I generate swagger docs by using `drf-yasg`. It looks at the serializers to generate the correct model definitions. So the serializers needs to represent the schema.

So this is where I am at, at the moment. Obviously now it fails because there is no `address` property in the `Person` model. How would you go about solving this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

from the [DRF-doc for `source`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)  says,

> The value `source='*'` has a special meaning, and is used to indicate
>   that the entire object should be passed through to the field. This can
>   be useful for creating nested representations, or for fields which
>   require access to the complete object in order to determine the output
>   representation.

So,try this,

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    streetname = serializers.CharField(source='address_streetname')
    housenumber = serializers.CharField(source='address_housenumber')
    zip = serializers.CharField(source='address_zip')


class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # .... your fields
    address = AddressSerializer(source='*')

    class Meta:
        fields = ('address', 'other_fields')
        model = Person
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just define a `property` within the serializer:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    address_streetname = models.CharField()
    address_housenumber = models.CharField()
    address_zip = models.CharField()

    @property
    def address(self):
        return {'streetname': self.address_streetname,
                'housenumber': self.address_housenumber,
                'zip': self.address_zip}
```

Comment: Yeah this would probably work fine for serialization. But not for deserialization. So my create/update actions would not work. Thanks though :)

Comment: yes you should to override the `create/update` actions.